# How to validate this hash parameter?

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape, grape-api

How do I write the correct `params` validations for this hash parameter:

```
{
  "files": {
    "main.c": {
      "contents": "#include <stdio.h> ...",
      "foo": "bar"
    },
    "main.h": {
      "contents": "#define BLAH ...",
      "foo": "baz"
    },
    ... more files here ...
  }
}
```

`files` is the hash parameter that I want to validate. Each key of `files` can be anything (a string); the values are hashes with a specific format that also needs to be validated (requires `contents` and `foo`).  I'm using grape 0.9.0.

This is kind of what I want to have:

```
params do
  optional :files, type: Hash do
    requires <any key>, type: Hash do
      requires :contents, type: String
      requires :foo, type: String
    end
  end
end
```

I've read the [documentation](https://github.com/intridea/grape/blob/master/README.md#parameter-validation-and-coercion) but I couldn't see how to achieve this kind of validation. Is it even possible? Do I need to write a custom validator?

---

An alternative is to have this instead:

```
{
  "files":
  [
    {
      "name":     "main.c",
      "contents": "#include <stdio.h> ...",
      "foo":      "bar"
    },
    {
      "name":     "main.h",
      "contents": "#define BLAH ...",
      "foo":      "baz"
    }
  ]
}
```

which can be easily validated like this:

```
params do
  optional :files, type: Array do
    requires :name, type: String
    requires :contents, type: String
    requires :foo, type: String
  end
end
```

but now I lose the ability to have unique file names.

Comment: What documentation have you read?  And what have you tried?

Comment: @vgoff I've read [these docs](https://github.com/intridea/grape/blob/master/README.md#parameter-validation-and-coercion). The only code I've tried is similar to the first ruby block in my question, but it always fails (I.e. `requires '*'` and `requires /.*/`, but I knew these wouldn't work anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [grape documentation](https://github.com/intridea/grape#parameter-validation-and-coercion) I would come up with the idea of writing your own custom validator and go with your second alternative.

```
class UniqueHashAttributes < Grape::Validations::Base
  def validate_param!(attr_name, params)
    # assuming @option is an array
    @option.each do |attribute|
      # detects if the value of the attribute is found more than once
      if params[attr_name].group_by { |h| h[attribute] }.values.collect(&:size).max > 1
        fail Grape::Exceptions::Validation, params: [@scope.full_name(attr_name)],
             message: "must have only unique values for properties: '#{@option.join(', ')}'"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It would also be possible to report custom errors that present the uniqueness violations. Of course this principle can also be applied to perform different kind of validations than the uniqueness.

If this validator is loaded in your application, you can utilize it in your `params` definition of the route as follows:

```
params do
  optional :files, unique_hash_attributes: [:name], type: Array do
    requires :name, type: String
    requires :contents, type: String
    requires :foo, type: String
  end
end
post '/validation' do
  'passed'
end
```

With this implementation you could also specify the `:foo` field (or any other) to be unique by adding it to the array of the unique hash attributes.

Any validations of the Hash's values (name, contents, foo) remain unchanged of the `files` validator and still apply.

A post request with the following data would not pass the verification:

```
{   "files":
  [
    {
      "name":     "main.c",
      "contents": "#include <stdio.h> ...",
      "foo":      "bar"
    },
    {
      "name":     "main.c",
      "contents": "#define BLAH ...",
      "foo":      "baz"
    }
  ]
}
```